# Webpack-Error - configuration.node has an unknown property 'Buffer'

Tags: node.js, windows, types

I have encountered an error when using the latest version of `Webpack (5.1.0)`. It looks like the configuration is throwing an error because the validation schema is too restrictive.

Here is the error message I am seeing.

**Error**

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object.
Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match 
the API schema.
 - configuration.node has an unknown property 'Buffer'. These properties are valid:
   object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Options object for node compatibility features.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I just want update the version of webpack from `4.x.x to 5.x.x` because I need a solution which was not present in its previous version.

**Versions**

```
- webpack: 5.1.0
- webpack-cli: 4.10.0
- webpack-dev-server: 4.13.2
```